# How to fix inner iframe scrolling of div in IOS safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a problem related to scrolling of iframe in iPad-Safari.I am developing a web-site, which contains some nested iframes and I am not able to scroll content inside the iframe in IOS (safari).

already putted the below code..

overflow:auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

but its not working....

Comment: "some nested iframes" sounds vague, and you're not really clear on what doesn't scroll, given these nested iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Das,

I think go to you this solution.

```
.div1{
   position:relative;  
}
span{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="div1">
  <span></span>
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d223978.0974992324!2d77.25494051113822!3d28.699882183239836!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x390cf1bb41c50fdf%3A0xe6f06fd26a7798ba!2sGhaziabad%2C+Uttar+Pradesh!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1518858854272" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Checkout this link [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu9ff8mn/11/)